# How to get updates from Asana via API

Tags: polling, asana, event-triggers

Right now I'm polling Asana every minute for updates to Tasks via Asana API.  Hopefully there's something like Event Triggers we can set to call some URL in our application.

I'd love to cut down the load we put on Asana servers and avoid timeouts that we are seeing every day.

Comment: Just following up to note that we launched this feature a few months ago, you can find the documentation at: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/events - let us know how it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana.) This is a very good question. Asana has actually been working on a subscriptions endpoint for the API, and has alpha-tested a version in the past. Finishing it up and launching it are on the near-term roadmap so in all likelihood you will hear something about it in the next few months.

Answer (score 0):

Asana now has beta support for webhooks which can "allow an application to be notified of changes" which can do away with polling:

- https://asana.com/developers/feed/webhooks-beta
- https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks

This is in addition to (and in a sense based on) "Events"  mentioned in the comments.